# Continuar procurando no mesmo Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho a string abaixo:

```
Tel.: 324234 --  2 123123 (22)
```

Quero retirar somente os dígitos depois de "Tel.:", ou seja, `324234212312322`, mas usando só 1 regex.

Eu consigo pegar os números depois de "Tel:" mas não todos depois.

Ja está feito neste site, podem testar?

https://regexr.com/4sspo

Como disse gostaria de usar o mesmo regex.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que capturar todos os dígitos após a palavra "Tel:" ignorando caracteres que não sejam dígitos seja impossível com uma só execução da regex.

A regex funciona analisando caractere por caractere, capturando somente aquilo que satisfaz a condição, então ao meu ver a melhor maneira de capturar o que deseja, seja através do uso de 2 regex:

- Uma regex irá capturar todos os caracteres após "Tel:" até a quebra de linha.
- Uma regex irá analisar o resultado da primeira regex e retornar somente os dígitos

Seguem as regex citadas:

- `/(?<=Tel\.:\s).*$/m`
- `/\d/g`

Implementação básica em JS:

```js
var rawData = `Casa - CEP 0334211 - Jardim Belém, Suzano, São Paulo
Quem recebe: Julio  Oliveira - Tel.: 145628 810 - 7469

Eu queria retirar 145628 + 810 + 7469
Ou seja: "1456288107469"

Só em 1 regex
Eu consigo fazer isso com outros passos mas gostaria de aprender a usar só 1 regex`

var regex1 = /(?<=Tel\.:\s).*$/m;
var regex2 = /\d/g

var fullMatch = rawData.match(regex1);

fullMatch.forEach((element) => {
  console.log('Resultado da primeira regex: ' + element);
  var result = element.match(regex2);
  console.log('Resultado da segunda regex: ' + result.toString().replace(/,/g,""));
//O replace junto ao toString() após o resultado é feito 
//para retirar o resultado do Array e remover todos os caracteres ",".
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex só busca padrões em um texto, mas a expressão em si não faz substituições. Se quer manipular o resultado encontrado, uma alternativa seria primeiro buscar os números que você quer (com os demais caracteres - traço, espaços, etc) e depois eliminar os caracteres que não são dígitos:

```js
let texto = `Casa - CEP 0334211 - Jardim Belém, Suzano, São Paulo
Quem recebe: Julio  Oliveira - Tel.: 145628 810 - 7469

Eu queria retirar 145628 + 810 + 7469
Ou seja: "1456288107469"

Só em 1 regex
Eu consigo fazer isso com outros passos mas gostaria de aprender a usar só 1 regex`;

//buscar os números depois de "Tel"
let match = texto.match(/Tel\.:((?:[^\d\n\r]*\d+)+)/);
if (match) {
    // eliminar os caracteres que não são dígitos
    console.log(match[1].replace(/\D+/g, '')); // 1456288107469
}
```

Repare que não preciso colocar "Tel.:" dentro de um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), acho desnecessário. Em vez disso, eu coloco o trecho que quero capturar dentro de parênteses, pois isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então será o grupo 1, que posso capturar depois na primeira posição do array `match` (dentro do `if`, quando faço `match[1]`).

Depois uso uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): `[^\d\n\r]`. Este trecho pega qualquer caractere que **não** seja um dígito (`\d`) ou uma quebra de linha (`\n` e `\r`). Fiz isso porque entendi que depois de "Tel.:", todos os números estão na mesma linha, e você quer pegar todos até o fim desta linha. Também coloco o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), indicando que podem ou não ter vários destes caracteres antes de um número.

Depois temos `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos). Você tinha usado `\d*`, mas esta expressão quer dizer "**zero** ou mais dígitos" (ou seja, se não tiver nenhum dígito, também serve). Usando `+`, você garante que deve ter pelo menos um dígito.

Toda essa sequência (não-dígitos seguido de dígitos) também tem um `+` logo depois, indicando que ela pode se repetir várias vezes (e o uso de `+` garante que ela deve ocorrer pelo menos uma vez).

Ou seja, tudo depois de "Tel.:" (desde que seja não-dígitos seguido de dígitos, repetido várias vezes, até o final da linha) estará no grupo 1. Em seguida, basta pegar o valor de grupo 1 (`match[1]`) e eliminar tudo que não for dígito (o `\D+` dentro do `replace` - e repare no uso da *flag* `g`, para que todas as ocorrências sejam substituídas). O que sobrar são somente os números.